# Eigenvalues of transfer matrix Ising model spin 1 system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model

I am calculating the partition function of an Ising model with spin 1 ($\sigma_i \in \{-1,0,1\}$) for $n$ sites. The following Hamiltonian has been used:

$$H = -J \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1},$$

assuming periodic boundary conditions, i.e. $\sigma_1 = \sigma_{n+1}$. From this I derived that $Z = \mathrm{tr}(P^n)$ where $P$ is the transfer matrix as follows:

\begin{equation}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
e^K & 1& e^{-K} \\
1&1&1\\
e^{-K} & 1& e^K
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
in the basis $\{|1\rangle,|0\rangle,|-1\rangle\}$ where $K := -\beta J$.

I know that $Z \approx \lambda^N$ for the greatest eigenvalue of $P$, however I cannot find the eigenvalues. I ended up with this characteristic equation that I cannot solve:

$$(e^K-\lambda)^2(1-\lambda) - 2(e^{K}-\lambda) + 2e^{-K}(1-\lambda)=0.$$

Could someone clarify how to proceed further?

Comment: Have you tried using Mathematica to solve your cubic equation?

Comment: No I am doing self-study on this topic and found this file: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-334-statistical-mechanics-ii-statistical-physics-of-fields-spring-2014/assignments/MIT8_334S14_pset4.pdf. There it is stated that it should be done by symmetry considerations

Comment: Well one eigenvector is clearly $(1,0,-1)^T$ with eigenvalue $2\sinh K$

Comment: When the matrix is symmetric and has lots of "kinda the same" elements, it's often a good idea to try various vectors made up of $1$, $-1$, and $0$. @mikestone gave you one eigenvector in that style, and it's easy to find another one in that style right away.

Comment: I get some different terms in the char. equation. Why don't you have an $e^{-2K}$ term?  I recommend you redo your equation without looking at your previous attempt.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the two other eigenvectors are of the form $(1,a,1)^T$  where $a$ is a real number. And by orthogonality of eigenvectors we can simply find two solutions for $a$ corresponding to the other eigenvalues. It seems general that we try to make the transfer matrix symmetric to exploit this property.